# I would like to prevent these entries from being added to the eventlog

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log

Our client's application EventLog is getting filled up with warnings due to a bug in the Microsoft SQL Server report viewer control, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973219.  They have thousands of users running reports so this is making their eventlog hard to use and they want them removed on a frequent basis.  I tried using PowerShell to remove the events, but that does not seem possible.  Is there a way to prevent these entries from being written to the event log in the first place?  I'm thinking I would like to filter out events where event source="ASP.NET 2.0.50727.0", eventId ="1309"  and Message contains "Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Server 2003 we wrote a custom app to do our filtering.

Windows Server 2008 has native filters: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd630944.aspx.